# Solidity Chainlink keepers with PriceFeeds

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

I'm trying to integrate Pricefeeds in the chain keepers to automate a sell order when the price goes under certain value.
Separately both work but when adding the Price feed function inside the `checkUpkeep()` it doesn't trigger the `performUpkeep()`.

Does `checkUpkeep()` function can call the priceFeed function or is not even praepared for this?

how should I implement it then?

Here is the code:

```
function checkUpkeep(bytes memory /* checkData */) public view override returns (//,bytes memory value
        bool upkeepNeeded, 
        bytes memory num
        ){

        uint256 EthPrice = 0;
        // uint256 i = 2;
        EthPrice = getPrice();
        num = abi.encodePacked(EthPrice);
        if (EthPrice > 0){
            upkeepNeeded = true;
        }

        return (upkeepNeeded, num);//, value
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata num) external override {//, bytes calldata value
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Order__UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_Wallets.length
            );
        }
        //Byte conversion to uint
        uint256 number;
        number = abi.decode(num, (uint256));

        // for(uint i=0;i<num.length;i++){
        //     number = number + uint(uint8(num[i]))*(2**(8*(num.length-(i+1))));
        // }
        s_nombre = number;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Oriok, in your last post, I noticed you are using Rinkeby testnet. Can you try the same code with Chainlink keepers and price feed in Goerli?

Comment: Yes, that's true realized few hours ago. Just integrated to Goerli and Keepers work but when integrating Pricefeeds it stop working. I'm trying to solve this now. When I call PriceFeed in a separate function it works normally so I don't know. Also I'm using Goerli address for priceFeed provided by the ChainLink doc.

Comment: I use the same code as you in `checkUpKeep` in my smart contract and the `performUpKeep` can be called by Chainlink keepers. Just one difference, why you use uint256 for price data? Price cannot be a negative number.

Comment: When you revalidate conditions in your `performUpKeep`, it seems that you are calling function incorrectly in `(bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("")`, the datatype is string while the bytes are required for `checkUpKeep()`

Comment: I'm using Uint256 for unsigned number so only positive numbers. I think I don't understand what is your point on this.
Also `(bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("")` in the patrick collins tutorial it says ("") calls the function without sending data.
Anyway Frank the code finally worked thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: yw, what did you do to make the code work?

Comment: I was deploying the contract and keepers with an already PerformUpkeep execution situation. I think this was the mistake, once I deployed and the condition to execute the performUpkeep was reached then everythink started working. Also had some sign mistakes in the code that make me expect some different outcome. I uploaded the code in github: https://github.com/obc92/MarketOrder. Now i want to implement a uniswapV3 sell function inside the performUpkeep so the code sells once a Stop loss is reached.